# Only the owner can delete his/her books?

Tags: security, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-acl

My problem is the other users that do not own the book but they can delete the book if they know the Book ID and it's very easy to get the Book ID.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here (ZF manual)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html)

See "Writing Conditional ACL Rules with Assertions". You will need to find a way to pass the book ID to the `assert()` method, but from then on it's easy.